# Does the dynamic snitching defeat the purpose of snitches?

Tags: cassandra

From 'Cassandra Definitive Guide':

> While Cassandra provides a pluggable way to statically describe your
> cluster’s topology, it also provides a feature called dynamic
> snitching that helps optimize the routing of reads and writes over
> time. Here’s how it works. Your selected snitch is wrapped with
> another snitch called the DynamicEndpointSnitch. The dynamic snitch
> gets its basic understanding of the topology from the selected snitch.
> It then monitors the performance of requests to the other nodes, even
> keeping track of things like which nodes are performing compaction.
> The performance data is used to select the best replica for each
> query. This enables Cassandra to avoid routing requests to replicas
> that are busy or performing poorly.

Dynamic snitch monitors the nodes, in addition to info provided by configured snitch.

Doesnt it make whole snitching process slow, defeating the very purpose of snitch?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesnt it make whole snitching process slow, defeating the very purpose of snitch?

Yes, it absolutely does suffer from the "observer effect."  Jon Haddad wrote an article a few years back (still relevant) where he covers this (point #5) and advocates for *disabling* it.

> Disable Dynamic Snitch

> Dynamic snitch is a feature that was intended to improve the performance of reads by preferring nodes which are performing better. Logically, it makes quite a bit of sense, but unfortunately it doesn’t behave that way in practice. In reality, we suffer from a bit of the Observer Effect, where the observation of the situation affects the outcome. As a result, the dynamic snitch generates quite a bit of garbage, so much in fact that using it makes everything perform significantly worse. By disabling it, we make the cluster more stable overall and end up with a net reduction in performance related problems. A fix for this is actively being worked on for Cassandra 4.0 in CASSANDRA-14459.

The full article "14 Things To Do When Setting Up a New Cassandra Cluster" can be found here:
https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2019/01/30/new-cluster-recommendations.html

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic snitching does not replace the function of snitches.

The configured snitch determines which racks and DCs the nodes belong to. It's the mechanism by which other nodes discover the placement of other nodes within the cluster.

Dynamic snitching on the other hand is an additional layer on top of snitches that routes requests away from nodes which are not performing well -- it does not determine where nodes are placed (which is the job of snitches).

If the dynamic snitching is doing its job, it improves the performance of the cluster because requests are diverted away from unhealthy nodes. Yes, it adds a bit more complexity but I disagree that it slows down the process. Cheers!

Comment: Ok. So what I understand now is that dynamic snitch keeps monitoring nodes in background, hence it has nodes' health info already with it, which it then used to route away from unhealthy nodes. It's not that it starts monitoring nodes when some request comes.